# Changing the Creation/Modification Dates of Nested Folders

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal, macintosh

I have 1,000,000 .mp4 files in a single folder (Mac) and was looking for some code that would move the files into dated folders based on their creation/modified dates (they are the same).

@pLumo came up with the following code that works using Terminal perfectly, creating hundreds of properly nested folders by day, month, and year:

```
cd /path/to/mp4-files/
for f in *.mp4; do
    date=$(stat -f %Sm -t %Y-%m-%d "$f")
    y=${date:0:4}
    m=${date:5:2}
    d=${date:8:2}
    target="Security Videos $y/Security Videos $y-$m/Security Videos $y-$m-$d"
    mkdir -p "$target"
    mv "$f" "$target"
done
```

I need one more piece to make this work, if someone can please help add the necessary lines, which is to set the creation/modification dates of all these newly added folders and subfolders to the most recent creation/modification file (or folder) contained inside.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Its not clear (to me at least) what you are asking. Is there some file or folder already present, and you want to change the creation and modification times for all files being moved to the parent folder to match the creation and modification time for the file or folder that was already present? Or do you mean something else?